# Understanding of Supspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $W$ be a subset of $V$. We define $W$ to be a subspace  if satisfies the following conditions:

(i) if $v,w$ are elements of $W$, their sum $v+w$ is also an element of $W$.

(ii) If $v$ is an element of $W$ and $c$ a number, then $cv$ is an element of $W$.

(iii) The element of $0$ of $V$ is also an element of $W$.

My question is that why there is not  the element of $1$ on the list?

Comment: Assume that $W\subset V = \mathbb R^2$ (all vectors with two real entries). $1$ is not even an element of $V$. So, why should it lie in $W$? The "element $0$ of $V$" is the zero vector which is an element of every vector space. It is NOT the number zero.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Propetry (iii) say that it is nonempty, is not?

Comment: Correct. Then $0\in W$ follows from (ii).

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Again, I have a question. So, '(iii)' is additive identity. Yet, there is not multiplicative identity, i.e., $1$ on the list. Why there is not multiplicative identity, i.e., $1$ on the list?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Why is (iii) "additive identity"? I don't see any addition there. And what would be a "multiplicative identity"? What do you mean by $1$?